# How do I force jQuery to stay local?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery as a dependency in a JavaScript 'plugin' of mine. I'm building the entire jQuery library into my function closure. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be an obvious way of **stopping** jQuery from going global and taking over `window`. [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) is all well and good, but I don't want my plugin to mess with the global name *jQuery* either, in case the site of the plugin already has a different version of it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.noConflict(true)` to unset the whole jQuery.

```
(function($){
    //...
})(jQuery.noConflict(true));
```

Comment: But by then, won't jQuery already have overwritten `window.jQuery` and broken any existing jQuery instance on the page?

Comment: @Codemonkey You add the code before or after loading other version of jquery, not the middle.

Comment: I mean I fear the following scenario: **1:** The website loads jQuery 1.4 **2:** My plugin loads jQuery 1.7.1 and overwrites *jQuery* and *$* **3:** I run `jQuery.noConflict` which unsets *jQuery* and *$* so they are "undefined"

Comment: @Codemonkey So after that load jQuery 1.4.2

Comment: I don't understand. I have no control over when the user of my plugin decides to load jQuery or my plugin. I just want the jQuery version inside my plugin not to interfere with the user's global scope.

Comment: @So how can you tell the user to use jQuery 1.7.1? What you should do is to tell the user your plugin needs jQuery 1.7, so load jQuery 1.7 then load your plugin. After that, the user can load jquery of other version what ever.

Comment: As I said, the jQuery 1.7.1 plugin is **built in** to my plugin, inside a function scope. I want the jQuery 1.7.1 version to exist only inside my plugin, not messing with the global scope

Comment: It's a node.js stitch module and [looks like this](http://pastebin.com/ViP1QnQj).

Answer (score 3):

```
// For example I have jQuery 1.2.6 from Drupal 6
// but some jquery plugins don`t work with this old version

// we have 1.2.6 version here

 var yourStruct = new function(){

    if(typeof(window.jQuery) == "function"){
        var oldJQuery = window.jQuery 
    }

    // jQuery v1.7 
     (function(a,b){function cA(a){return .............. // jQuery code


    var jQuery = window.jQuery ; // create jQuery varible in local scope

    if(typeof(oldJQuery) == "function"){
        window.jQuery = oldJQuery; 
    }

    this.version = function() {
        // in this plase we always have 1.7 version of jQuery
        return jQuery.fn.jquery;

    }
}

// we have 1.2.6 version here

console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery); // 1.2.6 
console.log(yourStruct.version()); // 1.7
```

**EDIT** you was right that `jQuery.noConflict(true)` do the same. I changed code little bit

```
 var yourStruct = new function(){

    // jQuery v1.7 
     (function(a,b){function cA(a){return f.isWindow(a) .........// jQuery code

    var jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true); // create jQuery varible in local scope
    var $ = jQuery;

    this.version = function() {
        // in this plase we always have 1.7 version of jQuery
        return jQuery.fn.jquery;
    }
    this.someFunction = function() {
        // Write your code specific for 1.7 version here    
    }

}

console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery); // 1.2.6 
console.log(yourStruct.version()); // 1.7
```

Comment: It actually seems that `jQuery.noConflict(true)` does all this automatically, so all you have to do is insert the jQuery code and run `var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);` and the global jQuery will remain the old version while the `jQuery` local will be *1.7.1*. It would be nice if you could confirm

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery, 'first');
        console.log($.fn.jquery, 'first');
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function ($) {
            console.log($.fn.jquery, 'closure');
        })(jQuery.noConflict(true));
    </script>
    <script>
        console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery, 'last');
        console.log($.fn.jquery, 'last');
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output of this code is

```
1.2.6 first 
1.2.6 first 
1.10.2 closure
1.2.6 last 
1.2.6 last
```